# Would you look for a clear all filters button on each individual filter?

Tags: website-design, filter, drop-down-list

On this said page there are 4 filters, here is the current design of the drop-down filter. 
However if you were to select say 20 of the 40 would you be looking for a "Clear Filter" button?
The cancel button just closes the dropdown and does not change the current selection or should that also clear selected filters?

I could add one in however what would the best order be? "Apply" "Clear Filter" "Cancel"?

[image: Filter]

Comment: I know this wasn't the question. Regarding the apply and cancel buttons the best practice is having the action button in the right. https://uxplanet.org/primary-secondary-action-buttons-c16df9b36150

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a drop down select box, so having *Cancel* is a bit weird in this context anyway.   I would expect to cancel by clicking the drop down arrow a second time, or clicking outside the menu.
In that case, you could use the space currently used as a cancel button as a *clear selection* button instead.

I would also swap the position of the *Apply* and *Clear* buttons, and make the clear a text button (text on a white background) instead of a full button, as it should not have equal presence as the *Apply* button.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your first option in a drop-down filter should be a Select All Option, on toggle on which you will select and unselect all filter values.

Comment: I see your point however, everything is selected by default it's only when you click on one does it then filter the whole page by what you've selected.